# JPA EntityManager Merge Exception

Tags: jpa, merge, entitymanager

I'm getting a `primaryKeyUpdateDisallowed ValidationException` when trying to merge an entity into the database when there is an existing entity with the same primary key.

Of course, I don't get the exception when I perform a `TypedQuery` and have the entity manager return the entity first, update the appropriate values, and then merge.  The problem is this process is too expensive, resource-wise. I need to be able to simply merge without the resulting exception.

Is there a way to structure our entity class so that we can over-write the records, including the primary keys? Or some other way around the problem?

Comment: Show us your code. This exception indicates that you're trying to change the value of the PK of a persistent entity, and this is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

In JPA, if you wish to do:

```
entityManager.merge(someEntity);
```

then you must first have someEntity loaded from the DB into the entityManager persistence context and then detached via "entityManager.detach(someEntity)" or by clearing the persistence context.  If someEntity is not pre-loaded and detached, but is instead created via "new SomeEntity()", then the merge() function will determine that you have added a new entity and carry out an internal operation very similar to entityManager.persist(someEntity).  When the data is flushed or committed in a transaction, it will generate a SQL INSERT, which will clash with the pre-existing PK.

Here's the specified behaviour from the JPA 2 spec:

---

*The semantics of the merge operation applied to an entity X are as follows:*

- *If X is a detached entity, the state of X is copied onto a pre-existing managed entity instance X' of the same identity or a new managed copy X' of X is created.*
- *If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is created and the state of X is copied into the new managed entity instance X'.*

---

*> The problem is this process is too expensive, resource-wise. I need to be able to simply merge without the resulting exception.*

This shouldn't be the case.  Retrieving the entity or list of entities from the DB should be efficient.  Possibly your query could be improved.  Do you have a "where" clause on the query?  Do you have much cascading of entities during refresh (via attribute cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH/ALL on relationships such as @OneToMany or @ManyToOne)?  Do you have a very complex inheritance hierarchy with many entities/tables?  If you could provide your JPQL or criteria query, I'm sure the problem will be simple to fix.  :-)